# Oracle unique constraint error when inserting

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint, ora-00001

```
INSERT INTO SS_ALERT_EVENTS (  ALERT_ID, EVENT_ID, TIME_DURATION, ALERT_EVENT_EFFECT, DATASET_ASSIGN_RULE, KEY_FIELDS_ASSIGN_RULE, SIDE, ALERT_VALIDATION_RULE, UNIQUE_ID ) VALUES ( 'test1', 7 ,  0, 1 ,  NULL,  '5b414c4552545f494e535452554d454e542e496e737472756d656e742049445d203a3d205b54524144455f5245504f52542e496e737472756d656e742049445d3b',  -1,  '5b414c4552542e416374696f6e5d203a3d20313b', 1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ESV31SURV.PK_SS_ALERT_EVENTS) violated
```

The EVENT_ID field is the problem. But I want to insert it anyway. However, when I try to drop the constraint of that name, it says there is no such constraint. Further, no such constraint is shown in USER_CONSTRAINTS table. What should I do?

Comment: If you don't see an object it doesn't mean it not exists - it just means that it was created from another schema. Log in as `sys` and look at constraints list again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The unique constraint might be in fact be a primary key constraint - at least that's what the name suggests.

Dropping the primary key of a table will potentially have very bad side effect it might break applications that rely on this primary key (and you will also have to drop all foreign keys that reference that table before you can drop the primary key)

That primary key was created with a purposes, so before blindly dropping it you should consult whoever created that schema and make sure that primary key is not needed (or should be redefined).

Having said all this: try to drop the PK using

```
ALTER TABLE SS_ALERT_EVENTS 
  DROP PRIMARY KEY
```

But please double check if this is really a wise decision!

Comment: "The unique constraint is in fact a primary key constraint - at least that's what the name suggests. " --- wrong. Look one more time at the query. It is not a primary key, it is a regular **unique constraint**.

Comment: @zerkms: a primary key **is** a unique constraint. Violating a PK constraint will throw an ORA-0001 just as violating a "regular" unique constraint. Try it out, both will give you exactly the same error

Comment: sorry, i need glasses :-( In some unknown reason I haven't seen in the first time that the constraint name `ESV31SURV.PK_SS_ALERT_EVENTS` contains `PK` prefix. Sorry. +1

Comment: @zerkms: A PK is also a unique constraint whereas a unique constraint is not necessarily a PK - I agree with you there. But from the error message you cannot tell whether the constraint is a PK or a "just" a unique constraint. Again: try it out. Both will throw ORA-0001. And the naming conventions usually used in the Oracle world do prefix the PK constraint with a PK - that's why I said "*that's what the name suggests*". I can be a "regular" unique constraint but it can also be a PK constraint

Comment: yes, yes, yes, you're absolutely correct. I just missed the PK part of constraint and thought it is a regular unique, sorry once again ;-) "But from the error message" --- sure, I proposed to look at the query which contains the table name + fields names and event_id obviously is a bad name for the table with `SS_ALERT_EVENTS` name. At least from my point of view.